# why the output is an address?

Tags: c++, arrays, linked-list

consider this is my code:

```
 void SportShoe::AddSportShoe() {   

    SportShoe MySepatu[SIZE];
    int numOfShoe = 0;
    nodeSport *tempShoe1; 

    while (numOfShoe < SIZE){
        cout << "Please enter the Shoe ID : (eg. 23210) " << endl;
        cin >> SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].ShoeID;

        cout << "Please enter the Shoe Brand: (eg. Adidas) " << endl;
        cin.sync();
        cin.getline(SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].BrandShoe,100); 

        cout << "Please enter the price of the Shoe : (eg. RM123.22) " << endl;
        cin >> SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].PriceShoe;
        cout << endl;

    //passing the value from 'MySepatu' to 'tempShoe'
        SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].ShoeID = (tempShoe1->ShoeIDList);
        SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].BrandShoe[100] = (tempShoe1->BrandShoeList[100]);
        SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].PriceShoe = (tempShoe1->PriceShoeList);

   //i do some dummy to see what stored in tempShoe1
       cout << "ID =>> " << tempShoe1->ShoeIDList << endl;
       cout << "Brand =>> " << tempShoe1->BrandShoeList << endl;
       cout << "Price =>> " << tempShoe1->PriceShoeList << endl;
    }

    while (numOfShoe >= SIZE-1){
       cout << ">> List is already full !! <<"; 
       system("PAUSE");
       MenuSportShoe();
    }
}
```

The code can be run as usual and doesn't show any error on the compiler. But, when it reach to the 'cout' area it'll print out something like an address of a pointer. Not the value.
Actually i think i use the wrong method to pass the value. I don't have idea on how to assign them.

//Here my class declaration

```
class SportShoe  {
private:
    struct nodeSport {
        int ShoeIDList;
        char BrandShoeList[100]; 
        float PriceShoeList; 
        nodeSport *last;
    };
    nodeSport *first = NULL; 

    struct Shoe  {
        int ShoeID;
        char BrandShoe[100]; 
        float PriceShoe; 
    }MySepatu[SIZE];

public:
    void AddSportShoe();
```

};

*i use array because i want to set a limit of the node. The linked list is useful for the other function like 'delete' , 'display', & etc.

Have any opinion to solve this and upgrade my code?

Comment: Maybe you can flesh this out to a [mcve] and include the output you're getting? You should probably also turn up the warnings in your compiler.

Comment: `SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].BrandShoe[100] = (tempShoe1->BrandShoeList[100]);` -- Explain what that line is supposed to do.  Whatever you think it does, it doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i'm trying to pass a value from 'MySepatu[SIZE]' to 'nodeShoe *tempShoe1'. That is the problem now. i don't know how is the legal method to do so.

Comment: `char a[100]; char b[100];`.  How do you assign the values in the `b` array to the `a` array?  That is the basic concept that you're missing, and probably you need to review your notes on functions such as `memcpy`, `strcpy`, etc.  Or better yet, just use `std::string` instead of char arrays.

Comment: Don't use c strings, use std::string. Don't use arrays, use std::array or std::vector or a similar container. This will sure fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use c strings, use std::string. Don't use arrays, use std::array or std::vector or a similar container. This will sure fix your problem.

```
class SportShoe  {
private:
    struct nodeSport {
        int ShoeIDList;
        std::string BrandShoeList; 
        float PriceShoeList; 
        nodeSport *last;
    };
    nodeSport *first = NULL; 

    struct Shoe  {
        int ShoeID;
        std::string BrandShoe; 
        float PriceShoe; 
    };
    std::array<Shoe, SIZE> MySepatu;

public:
    void AddSportShoe();
};

void SportShoe::AddSportShoe() {   
    std::array<SportShoe, SIZE> MySepatu;
    int numOfShoe = 0;
    nodeSport *tempShoe1; 

    while (numOfShoe < SIZE){
        cout << "Please enter the Shoe ID : (eg. 23210) " << endl;
        cin >> SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].ShoeID;

        cout << "Please enter the Shoe Brand: (eg. Adidas) " << endl;
        cin.sync();
        std::getline(cin, SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].BrandShoe); 

        cout << "Please enter the price of the Shoe : (eg. RM123.22) " << endl;
        cin >> SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].PriceShoe;
        cout << endl;

    //passing the value from 'MySepatu' to 'tempShoe'
        SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].ShoeID = tempShoe1->ShoeIDList;
        SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].BrandShoe = tempShoe1->BrandShoeList;
        SportShoe::MySepatu[numOfShoe].PriceShoe = tempShoe1->PriceShoeList;

   //i do some dummy to see what stored in tempShoe1
       cout << "ID =>> " << tempShoe1->ShoeIDList << endl;
       cout << "Brand =>> " << tempShoe1->BrandShoeList << endl;
       cout << "Price =>> " << tempShoe1->PriceShoeList << endl;
    }

    while (numOfShoe >= SIZE-1){
       cout << ">> List is already full !! <<"; 
       system("PAUSE");
       MenuSportShoe();
    }
}
```